# Application throwing time out exception on sending bulk data

Tags: c#, asp.net, console-application

I have a Console Application which consumes a BizTalk Web Service. The Problem is that when I send the BizTalk Service object data in bulk, my console application throws the exception:

> Application has either timed out or is Timing out.

My application actually needs to wait for the Biztalk service to finish processing its job. Increasing the `obj.Timeout` value was of no help. Is there anything else other than using `Thread.Sleep` method (which I want to avoid)?

Below is the relevant code snippet from my application:

```cs
pumpSyncService.Timeout = 750000;
outputRecords = pumpSyncService.PumpSynchronization(pumpRecords);
```

The pump records contain an array of objects. When the count is around `30`, I get a correct response, but when the count increases to around `150` I get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending smaller chunks in a loop. Instead of sending 150 all at once, send 30 records 5 times. The timeout might be happening because it takes too long to send 150 records.

Comment: But that would require the web service hit again and again..the count will increase to nearly 1000 in production...loads of performance issues can arise...

Comment: That is true, but your other option is to set the timeout higher, which is not a great practice.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to send all 30 at once , if the service allows you to.  I am assuming you have verified that the event kicking this off is not firing 5 times .  try it asynchronously and process your results when they come back.

Comment: I am able to send all 150 at once..the problem is it takes long to process..my console app doen't wait for that long...how will i process it asynchronously? The web service is exposed from a different team...I cannot modify anything from their side...

Comment: The timeout might happen because it takes too long to send 150 rows of data to the web service. Your application is sitting there waiting for a reply, but the reply will only be sent once all the data has been received by the web service.